# PHP Object Oriented Issue On My Code

Tags: php, oop, class, inheritance, extend

Hi please have a look on bellow code.

```
<?php
class A
{
    public $name;

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    public function setName()
    {
        $this->name = 'Prasad';
    }
}

$obj = new B();

echo $obj->getName();

?>
```

Here It's display nothing when I echo the name. Related to the $name in class A. Is this issue is with getName or setName? How can I set the $name variable in class A from extended class B. And how can I get that from a class B object. Appreciate any hint or explanation on what I have missed.

Comment: Have you tried calling `setName()` first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't set the name (using `$obj->setName()`) before.

Comment: Great... Thanks for pinting that out.

Answer (score 1):

You are most of the way there with your code, in fact you would have a working example if you added a line telling the code to call the `setName()` function:

```
$obj = new B();
$obj->setName();
echo $obj->getName();
```

More typically you would use a `set` function with a parameter, then pass the value you want to set. You would also set the `$name` property to `protected`, which means the value must be accessed via the set & get methods (more on [visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) in the manual):

```
<?php
class A
{
    protected $name;

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}

$obj = new B();
$obj->setName('Prasad');
echo $obj->getName();

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Technically, it's echoing the `$name` variable (which is undefined at that point).  Unfortunately, it hasn't been set yet.  Try using `$obj->setName()` to set the name.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as SomeKittens suggested you need to call setName() first.

```
class A
{
    public $name;

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    public function setName()
    {
        $this->name = 'Prasad';
    }
}

$obj = new B();
$obj->setName();
echo $obj->getName();
```

However, it might be better to perform the setting of the name in the constructor of `B`, as:

```
class A
{
    public $name;

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    public function B()
    {
        $this->name = 'Prasad';
    }
}

$obj = new B();

echo $obj->getName();
```

This printed `Prasad` for me using http://writecodeonline.com/php/ to test the code.

Even better, pass the name 'Prasad' when creating the new `B` object, as:

```
class A
{
    public $name;

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    public function B( $value = 'Prasad' )
    { 
        $this->name = $value;
    }
}

$obj = new B();

echo $obj->getName(), "<br>";

$obj = new B( 'John' );

echo $obj->getName();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you aren't setting the name attribute first. Call `B->setName()` and then you can get the name by calling `B->getName()`.

Comment: `setName()` without params because the name are static, in this case.